# Comparing three pandas columns to determine a prediction

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a function to compare three columns (Versicolor, Virginica, Virginica) in a pandas dataframe to set value to a fourth column.

Essentially I have two binary classifications in serial.

First I need to compare Versicolor vs Virginica. If Versicolor is '1', then set the Predictions row to 'versicolor'. Else if Versicolor is 0, then check if Virginica is '1' or '0'. If Virginica is '1',then set the Predictions row to 'virginica', else set the Predictions row to 'setosa'.

```
Versicolor: [0 0 0 1 0 1 0] 
Virginica:  [1 0 0 0 1 1 1] 
Setosa:     [0 1 1 0 0 0 1]

Predictions: [virginica, setosa, setosa, versicolor, virginica, versicolor, virginica]
```

Comment: Do you need `df.idxmax(axis=1)` ? What happens if all `0` ?

Comment: Let's assume all equal to zero is not possible in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
s = df.idxmax(axis=1).values.tolist()
print (s)
['Virginica', 'Setosa', 'Setosa', 'Versicolor', 'Virginica', 'Versicolor', 'Virginica']
```

For new column:

```
df['new'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

Numpy solution:

```
df['new'] = df.columns[df.values.argmax(axis=1)]
```